# Inheritance and base class method call python

Tags: python, inheritance

I would like a method in a base class to call another method in the same class instead of the overriding method in an inherited class.
I would like the following code to print out

Class B: 6

Class A: 9

Can this be done?

---

```
# Base class definition
class ClassA(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Initializing A")

    # hoping that this function is called by this class's printFnX
    def fnX(self, x):
        return x**2

    def printFnX(self, x):
        print("ClassA:",self.fnX(x))

# Inherits from ClassA above
class ClassB(ClassA):
    def __init__(self):
        print("initizlizing B")

    def fnX(self, x):
        return 2*x

    def printFnX(self, x):
        print("ClassB:", self.fnX(x))
        ClassA.printFnX(self,x)

bx = ClassB()
bx.printFnX(3)
```

Comment: Do you care to reconsider which answer you've marked as accepted?   the current selection is really bad advice for most people and most use cases.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

The same can be achieved by making `fnX` and `printFnX` both classmethods.

```
class ClassA(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print("Initializing A")

    # hoping that this function is called by this class's printFnX
    @classmethod
    def fnX(self, x):
        return x ** 2

    @classmethod
    def printFnX(self, x):
        print("ClassA:",self.fnX(x))

class ClassB(ClassA):
    def __init__(self):
        print("initizlizing B")

    def fnX(self, x):
        return 2*x

    def printFnX(self, x):
        print("ClassB:", self.fnX(x))
        ClassA.printFnX(x)


bx = ClassB()<br>
bx.printFnX(3)
```

Comment: This is better than the other answer ... more elegant. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't even work.  Try to access an instance variable such as ``self.y`` from inside fnX.  In a classmethod, the *self* variable  no longer holds the instance; instead, it becomes the class of the caller's instance, so you've completely lost access to instance variables.  This "pattern" is a disaster and something that shouldn't be used in code you care about.

Comment: I agree, it just answered his original question, that is it with all the drawbacks you just described. There is no pattern here per se.

Answer (score 50):

Congratulations, you've discovered the motivating use case for Python's double-underscore name mangling :-)

For the details and a worked-out example see: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables and at http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers .

Here's how to use it for your example:

```
# Base class definition
class ClassA(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Initializing A")

    # hoping that this function is called by this class's printFnX
    def fnX(self, x):
        return x**2
    __fnX = fnX

    def printFnX(self, x):
        print("ClassA:",self.__fnX(x))

# Inherits from ClassA above
class ClassB(ClassA):
    def __init__(self):
        print("initizlizing B")

    def fnX(self, x):
        return 2*x

    def printFnX(self, x):
        print("ClassB:", self.fnX(x))
        ClassA.printFnX(self,x)

bx = ClassB()
bx.printFnX(3)
```

The use case is described as a way of implementing the [Open-Closed Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) in "The Art of Subclassing" found at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yrboy25WKGo&noredirect=1 .

Comment: Very insightful. Now I know what double-underscore naming of methods is useful for!

Comment: What might not be obvious is that methods in the base class must be public or you must use the fully mangled name.
Python does not have a "protected" or "friend" qualifier, so when refactoring simply moving `def __doSomething(self):' from the super class to the base class will not make it accessible from the super class. You'll either have to make it public `def doSomething(self):' or use the mangled name.