# python inheritance function override during init

Tags: python, inheritance, initialization, overriding

Somehow the Father class can see the methods of the Child class. I presumed that only internal methods are available to Father during **init**

But apparently I am wrong. Here is the code:

```
class Father():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name=self.getName()
        print "from Father ->", self.name

    def getName(self):
        return "father"

class Child(Father):
    def __init__(self):         
        Father.__init__(self)
        self.name=self.getName()
        print "from Child ->", self.name

    def getName(self):
        return "child"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys, pprint

    someone=Child()
```

And the output is

```
from Father -> child
from Child -> child
```

But I would like to get

```
from Father -> father
from Child -> child
```

Any thoughts how to rewrite it ? Tnx !

Comment: That is perfectly normal behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the purpose for [name-mangling](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers): It allows you to say: "This class's attribute":

```
class Father():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name=self.__getName()
        print "from Father ->", self.name
    def __getName(self):
        return "father"

class Child(Father):
    def __init__(self):         
        Father.__init__(self)
        self.name=self.__getName()
        print "from Child ->", self.name

    def __getName(self):
        return "child"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys, pprint

    someone=Child()
```

yields

```
from Father -> father
from Child -> child
```

For more information, see also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7841971/190597).

Comment: Now I need to figure how to ask the owner of the Father class to change his code. Because I am writing the Child class ... hmm ...